# Warning: PDOStatement::execute() expects parameter 1 to be array, string given in C:\xampp\htdocs\php-login\upload.php on line 25

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Buenos días comencé hace unos días a programar en PHP con Mysql, pero estoy teniendo problemas para actualizar la base de datos.

Creé un login y un registro, ahora estoy buscando actualizar la información del perfil del usuario, para ser mas específicos la foto de perfil pero me surge el error señalado en el titulo.

Este es el código:

```
<?php

class DBImagen
{

    private $DBConexion;

    function __construct($Conexion)
    {
        $this->DBConexion = $Conexion;
    }

    /**********************************
    Función para guardar la ruta de la
       Imagen en la base de datos
    **********************************/
    public function uploadImage($Imagen)
    {
        $ruta = 'imagenes/'.$Imagen['imagen']['name'];
        move_uploaded_file($Imagen['imagen']['tmp_name'],$ruta);
        $sql =("UPDATE users SET 'urlPhoto'= ? WHERE 'email' = :email");
        $stmt = $this->DBConexion->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->execute($ruta);
        $results = $stmt->fetch(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    }

    /**********************************
    Función visualizar las imagenes 
    que estan en la ruta guardada en la 
    BD
    **********************************/
    public function viewImages()
    {
        $SQLStatement = $this->DBConexion->prepare("SELECT * FROM users");
        $SQLStatement->execute();

        while($img = $SQLStatement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
        {
        ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php print($img['id']);?></td>
            <td><center><img src="<?php print($img['urlPhoto']); ?>" width="200"></center></td>
        </tr>
        <?php 
        }
    }

}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hola estás tratando de ejecutar una sentencia preparada, en la que algunos puntos de entrada de valores se representan con marcadores con nombre `:email` mientras que otros son posicionales `'urlPhoto' = ?` eso hace que la sentencia esté mal definida. Debes construirla así:

```
<?php
$sql = 'UPDATE users SET urlPhoto = :url WHERE email = :email ;'
// Observa que sólo uso comillas simples y no me fijo en los tipos de datos
// es una de las ventajas de usar marcadores posicionales con nombre.

// Ahora construyo la sentencia preparada
$stmt = $this->DBConexion->prepare($sql);
// Preparo el array de valores a pasar al ejecutar la consulta
// Nota no recogiste el email
$useremail = 'algún valor que has debido recoger';
$keyedvalues = [':url' => $ruta, ':email' => $useremail];

// Finalmente ejecuto la sentencia pasando un el array de valores
// tu no lo pasaste, pasaste en su lugar el path a la imagen
$stmt->execute($keyedvalues);
```

El resto del código no lo revisé. No aporta a la solución del problema.

Comment: Muy buenos días, gracias por tomarse la molestia de contestar, probé su código, ahora no marca ningún error en pantalla, subo la foto y es guardada en la carpeta  imágenes sin ningún problema como lo hacia, pero la ruta no se agrega a la base de datos, como dije tampoco surge ningún error en pantalla así que me cuesta trabajo darme cuenta el porque sucede esto.

Comment: Es posible que no esté pasando correctamente el correo que se usa como identificador en la condición `WHERE email = :email` recuerde que en el código que se mostraba inicialmente no se estaba recogiendo el valor. Si necesita verificar si hubo o no error luego de `$stmt->execute()` puede hacer `$error = $stmt->errorInfo();` y acto seguido un dump para revisarlo.

Answer (score 0):

Hay varios problemas en esta función:

```
public function uploadImage($Imagen)
{
    $ruta = 'imagenes/'.$Imagen['imagen']['name'];
    move_uploaded_file($Imagen['imagen']['tmp_name'],$ruta);
    $sql ="UPDATE users SET 'urlPhoto'= ? WHERE 'email' = :email";
    if ( $stmt = $this->DBConexion->prepare($sql) ) {

        $stmt->execute($ruta);
    $results = $stmt->fetch(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
}
```

1. En la variable `$sql` estás mezclando dos estilos de poner los marcadores. PDO permite usar marcadores de posición, que son representados por el signo `?` y marcadores de nombre, que se usan con la notación `:nombre`, como haces con `:email`. Pero debes decidirte por uno de los dos, no mezclar.
2. Cuando pasas los parámetros mediante el método `execute()` tienes que pasar un array con cada valor, no una cadena. Aunque sea un solo valor, tienes que pasarlo en un array. Si usas marcadores de posición  `?` pasas sólo los valores en el orden en que deben ser asignados según la consulta. Si usas marcadores de nombre debes pasar en el array cada `:nombre` con su valor correspondiente. Algo así: `array (':nombre'=>$valorParaNombre)`.
3. En `$sql` estás usando un marcador `:email`, pero en el contexto no se ve cuál sería el valor para esa columna ¿? También, el identificador que suele usar MySQL son los backticks o comillas invertidas no las comillas simples `'`. Y, siempre en `$sql`, no necesitas usar paréntesis para definir la variable.
4. En `$results` no sé que hacen los parámetros `PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION` dentro de `fetch` ¿? Esos son atributos de la configuración de PDO. Además, una consulta `UPDATE` no devuelve resultados, no sé para qué usas `fetch` ahí. A lo sumo lo que aplicaría sería verificar si hubieron filas actualizadas usando `rowCount()`. Además, no haces nada con `$results`, ni la retornas, ni la imprimes. Si no la vas a usar, no la crees.

Corrigiendo la función, quedaría así (**haciendo constar que necesitas poner en ese contexto el valor que iría en `email`**):

---

#### Nueva versión con control estricto de errores:

---

```
public function uploadImage($Imagen)
{
    $ruta = 'imagenes/'.$Imagen['imagen']['name'];
    move_uploaded_file($Imagen['imagen']['tmp_name'],$ruta);
    if ($this->DBConexion) {
            $sql ="UPDATE `users` SET `urlPhoto`= ? WHERE `email` = ?";
            if ( $stmt = $this->DBConexion->prepare($sql) ) {
                #Definimos un array para los parámetros
                #OJO, falta la variable $email en tu contexto
                $mParams=array($ruta,$email);
                #Pasamos $mParams a execute
                if ( $stmt->execute($mParams) ) {
                    #Lo que aplicaría aquí sería obtener las filas afectadas... y retornarlo
                    return $stmt->rowCount();
                } else {
                    return "Error ejecutando con SQLSTATE: ".$stmt->errorInfo()[0];
                }
            } else {
                return "Error preparando con SQLSTATE: ".$this->DBConexion->errorInfo()[0];
            }
    } else {
        return "Error: no hay conexión";
    }
}
```

Comment: Muy buenos días, gracias por tomarse la molestia de contestar, probé su código, ahora no marca ningún error en pantalla, subo la foto y es guardada en la carpeta  imágenes sin ningún problema como lo hacia, pero la ruta no se agrega a la base de datos, como dije tampoco surge ningún error en pantalla así que me cuesta trabajo darme cuenta el porque sucede esto.

Comment: @AlexisAguirre revisa la **Nueva versión con control estricto de errores**. Como ya se ha dicho, debes **poner en el contexto la variable para`$email`**. Y recuerda recuperar el retorno de `uploadImage()` cuando haces la llamada para mostrarlo en pantalla. Si no te funciona, actualiza la pregunta poniendo al final el nuevo código que has implementado, cómo has hecho la llamada y qué imprime en pantalla.